# Writing a collection to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working in VS2005 and I need the C# syntax write to write collection values in an Excel sheet. I initialize the collection like this:

```
Reports oReports =new Reports();//oReports is a collection
```

Assuming that this collection has values, how would I write them to Excel?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something quick and dirty if you don't want to faff around learning how to write to Excel - just write out to a .csv file, open it yourself in excel and save as Excel format.

Just output in a stream, such as: (will work if your report values have commas in them too)

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\file.csv"))
{
    StringBuilder csvLine = new StringBuilder();

    //Enter your header row here:
    csvLine.Append("Header1,Header2,Header3");
    sw.WriteLine(csvLine.ToString());

    foreach (Report report in Reports)
    {
        csvLine = new StringBuilder();
        csvLine.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", report.Value1));
        csvLine.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", report.Value2));
        csvLine.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\"", report.Value3)); //etc
        sw.WriteLine(csvLine.ToString());
    }
    sw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: To work with elements containing commas enclose the string with 2 double quotes.
 csvLine.Append("\"");
 csvLine.Append(string.Format("{0},", report.Value1));
 csvLine.Append("\"");

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the collection and add the collection values to cells in your spreadsheet.

Here's a couple links on how to work with an excel spreadsheet in .Net

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/ExcelAutomation01052007080910AM/ExcelAutomation.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;302084

Comment: Would you like to send some syntax.....I just want to write in  Excel from the collection ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The samples provided show how to write to excel in .Net.  Do you not know how to work with the collection in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your reports to an object array (two dimensional), and assign the array to an excel range